# Dynamically generate exportAs variable value Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-directive

Hi I have a directive as below,

```
@Directive({
      selector: '[changeColor]',
      exportAs:'changeColor' 
    })
    export class ColorDirective {
@Input('mfData') public inputData: any[] = [];
        constructor(elem: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer2) {
           renderer.setStyle(elem.nativeElement, 'color', 'red');
console.log(this.inputData, 'inputData');
        }
    }
```

And use it as below:

```
<h1 #x=changeColor>Hello</h1>
```

What if my `x` value is dynamically generating (inside ngFor). How can add an index infront or after x, so that my x value will be unique? like below

```
<h1 #x1=changeColor>Hello1</h1>
<h1 #x2=changeColor>Hello2</h1>
....
<h1 #xn=changeColor>Hellon</h1>
```

Please help me guys on this.. TIA

Updated HTML with @Input variable

```
<div class="col-12 u-grey-container table--section u-margin-bottom-8" *ngFor="let color of colorList;let ndx = index">

 <table class="table table-striped" [mfData]="color.list" #main="changeColor" *ngIf="color.list" (mfSelectedEntities)="selectedRecords($event, schedule)">
<thead> ... </thead>
<tbody>
<template let-item ngFor [ngForOf]="main.data" let-ndx="index">
...
</tbdoy>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Just use `#x="changeColor"` inside `*ngFor` loop

Comment: @yurzui It is already inside a *ngFor..

Comment: Then it should work

Comment: when i console in my directive, if there is multiple directives its always getting the first reference

Comment: https://ng-run.com/edit/mBDQgjKiS2PoJeWcLqD4

Comment: Lets say i have an@Input, `@Input('mfData') public inputData: any[] = []; every time I console inside my component, its the first reference's data.. Thats the problem

Comment: Where do you have that input? I don't see the problem here because you can refer to any directive in array through index

Comment: https://ng-run.com/edit/mBDQgjKiS2PoJeWcLqD4?open=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Edited my question with Input

Comment: Can you also add template and where you console it?

Comment: Updated my question.